# Не появляется кнопка merge в github

Tags: git, github

Сделал pull request из своей ветки в main, его одобрили, но кнопка merge не появилась. Все новые commit я подтянул в свою ветку и в команде разработчиков я есть.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно - нет доступа на запись, который необходим чтобы объединять ветки.

Comment: Кнопка слияния видна у автора репозитория (ну или участников с правом слияния в этот репозиторий), куда вы вливаете, а не у вас.

Comment: Кнопка merge видна у разработчиков, имеющих права на сливание с защищенной веткой. По идее это те же люди, что и выставляют одобрения

Comment: Все ясно, спасибо.